# Matching a SQL command with database

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, web-sql

I am using webdb for client side and I want to match the server side database so the web app can be used offline. This here is the script for creating the server side table...

```
USE [TESTDB]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tblInternalMobile_SalesCalls]    Script Date: 01/08/2013 11:30:31 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblInternalMobile_SalesCalls](
    [newcall_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [companyname] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [comment] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [dateUTC] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblInternalMobile_SalesCalls] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [newcall_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

I am trying to match that on the client side but around identity I get an error `Uncaught Error: [object SQLError], Error Code: 5, Error Message: could not prepare statement (1 near "IDENTITY": syntax error)`

This is my client side code...

```
//Database helper
//I want to use a 'namespace' for this to minimize name conflicts
var DbHelper = {};
//use the webDb 'namespace' so we could use indexDb if need be in the future by making a new 'namespace'
DbHelper.webDb = {};
//To store the database object
DbHelper.webDb.db = null;
//Open the database
DbHelper.webDb.openDb = function() {
    var dbSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024 //5MB I believe is the max
    DbHelper.webDb.db = openDatabase("TestDB", "1.0", "Database manager", 5 * 1024 * 1024);
};
//If there is an error its going to throw an error, I havent added any handlers for this, so it should be added where the function is called
DbHelper.webDb.onError = function(tx, e) {
    throw "Error: " + e + ", Error Code: " + e.code + ", Error Message: " + e.message;
};
//This should be used if we are doing a non query, where we dont need to use the result
DbHelper.webDb.onSuccess = function(tx, r) {
    console.log("Database result: " + r)
};
//Create the tables we are going to use
DbHelper.webDb.createTables = function() {
    var db = DbHelper.webDb.db;
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        //I am using the same tables as I am on the server, so we dont confuse things
        tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblInternalMobile_SalesCalls(newcall_id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), companyname varchar(30), comment varchar(300), dateUTC DATETIME2)", [], DbHelper.webDb.onSuccess, DbHelper.webDb.onError);
    });
}
DbHelper.webDb.init = function() {
    DbHelper.webDb.openDb();
    DbHelper.webDb.createTables();
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    DbHelper.webDb.init();
});
```

Why the heck isn't it working? I believe I am using the right syntax, obviously not.

The problem is this statement `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblInternalMobile_SalesCalls(newcall_id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), companyname varchar(30), comment varchar(300), dateUTC DATETIME2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're actually using SQL Server or one of its variants on the client side as well as on the server side, you should probably use the same CREATE TABLE statement. But SQL Server doesn't support CREATE TABLE *IF NOT EXISTS*.

If you're using **the [deprecated HTML5 interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#web-sql)**, your user agent is expected to conform to SQLite syntax.

```
CREATE TABLE tblInternalMobile_SalesCalls(
  newcall_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
  companyname varchar(30), 
  comment varchar(300), 
  dateUTC DATETIME2
);
```

I believe w3.org's [Indexed Database API](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/) is intended to supersede webdb.

Comment: The server side is mssql so its not the same as webdb the create table part isn't the problem.

Comment: Well, a syntax error near "IDENTITY" suggests your CREATE TABLE statement *is* the problem. What is your client-side database?

Comment: webdb... I know it is create table. It is the only statement being executed. The question is more directed at what is wrong with it

Comment: webdb isn't a dbms, it's an interface. If it's the [interface specified by w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#web-sql), "User agents must implement the SQL dialect supported by Sqlite 3.6.19." Syntax for [SQLite3 CREATE TABLE statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) SQLite doesn't support the keyword "IDENTITY".

Comment: Thats what I wanted^ I realised that after using sqlfiddle

Comment: Also if you notice I have made plans to move to indexdb. However I want to use sql for the prototyping.